# I have a Tabbed activity, it works fine in portrait mode, but it stops showing data in landscape mode. and swipe also won't work perfectly in tabs

Tags: android, tabs, orientation, landscape, portrait

Changing orientation back to portrait also won't work. I have to close and open the app again.

## Here is my layout for main activity

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
>         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
>         app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
>         android:id="@+id/tabs"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         app:tabGravity="fill"
>         app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
>         app:tabMode="fixed" />
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
> ```
>
> #### I have used app:tabGravity="fill" app:tabMaxWidth="0dp" app:tabMode="fixed"
>
> ```
> <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>     android:id="@+id/view_pager"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /> </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
> ```

#### I am using 2 tabs. one contains a listview and other contains grid view.

#### MainActivity

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
       prefManager.setFromActivity(false);
       commonMethods = new CommonMethods();
       sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);
       viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager); 

       viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


           }

           @Override
           public void onPageSelected(int position) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


           }
       });


       tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
       tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

setUpFrag();
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "F1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "F2");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

public void setUpFrag() {
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

    }
```

### Here fragment1 is showing list and fragment2 is showing album grid.

Which is working perfectly in portrait mode.

Comment: Can you share us your code of the activity?

Comment: Any error in Logcat?